# Is there a better/cleaner way to selectively delete cookies in Chrome other than going to “chrome://settings/content/all?”

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome allows us to selectively delete cookies at this link:

```
chrome://settings/content/all
```

In my case I have visited hundreds of websites. I want to delete cookies from most of them but not all. Deleting them one by one by clicking with the mouse will take an onerous amount of time and is sure to cause me RSI (carpal tunnel).

Is there any cleaner way to do it from command line and such?

Comment: Not currently. If it's something you really need to do, you may be able to use an SQLite client to manually edit the Cookies file in `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network`. They are also encrypted, so you may need to [decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611673/7411885) them to see the associated URLs

Comment: Firefox and Edge allow you to clear cookies using the menu that you get when you click the padlock on the left side of the address bar. On both those browsers you get a "site cookies" items that allows you to selectively delete cookies for the current site. I don't know if that menu exists in Chrome.

Comment: @Mokubai that option is also present in any chromium browser, including Google Chrome. But that would still mean you have to click it for lots of sites, which OP specifically mentioned they did not want to.

Comment: I would look into how many of the sites you want to keep the cookies for and determine if you really need them. Cookies are often just storing login credentials, and logging in manually is something you can easily do. Deleting all cookies and then login to those sites is most likely the quickest and easiest way to go.